# Nginx with ruby on rails got 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

Some time my server got this error

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <center>
            <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
        </center>
        <hr>
            <center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
        </body>
    </html>
    <!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
    <!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
    <!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
    <!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
    <!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
    <!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

after restart it working normal. I don't know why. I'm appreciate with any help .

Thanks

This is my Nginx config, it run with Unicorn .

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 10;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;


    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    upstream app_server { server unix:/tmp/unicorn.spui.sock fail_timeout=0; }
    upstream faye_server { server 127.0.0.1:9292 fail_timeout=0; }
        upstream seo_server  { server 127.0.0.1:8000 fail_timeout=0; }

        # CACHE
        proxy_cache_path /var/www/cache keys_zone=seo:10m;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

When i coming server see the error log i got.

```
2507 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.spui.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
```

Comment: Please provide more information. Can you show yours Nginx configuration? Whar ROR code you're trying to run?

Comment: restart what? nginx or ror server? what ror server do u use?

Comment: @LeonardoWong I'm restart the nginx . i'm using amazon  server

Comment: @michalczukm i have update my config, please take look . thanks for your time